# android studio build wrong : facebook/react/react-native/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 502

Tags: android-studio

> Could not GET
> 'https://google.bintray.com/exoplayer/com/facebook/react/react-native/maven-metadata.xml'.
> Received status code 502 from server: Bad Gateway

Answer (score 0):

Bintray and JCenter are deprecated now. Prefer Maven Central and Google's Maven repo.
Use them like this:

```
repositories {
  mavenCentral()
  google()
}
```

And remove all instances of `jcenter()`, `google.bintray.com` and `dl.bintray.com`